# Learning JS... seem to be stuck on this exercise... not sure what I'm doing wrong

Tags: javascript

This is an exercise for an online class... not sure what I'm doing wrong. The wording of what I'm supposed to do isn't really well detailed.

```
function exerciseFour(value){
  let greaterThanFive = false;
  // In this exercise, you will be given a variable, it will be called: value
  // You will also be given a variable named: greaterThanFive
  // Using an 'if' statement check to see if the value is greater than 5. If it is, re-assign greaterThanFive the boolean true.
  if (value > 5) {
    let greaterThanFive = true;
  }

  // Please write your answer in the line above.
  return greaterThanFive;
}

function exerciseFive(name){
  let isSondra = false;
  // In this exercise, you will be given a variable, it will be called: name
  // You will also be given a variable named: isSondra
  // Using an 'if' statement check to see if the name is equal to the string 'Sondra'. If it is, re-assign isSondra the boolean true.
  if (name === 'Sondra') {
    let isSondra = true;
  }

  // Please write your answer in the line above.
  return isSondra;
}
```

Comment: `let greaterThanFive = true;` you are declaring a variable with the same name, shadowing the outer one. Remove the `let`.

Comment: You can set the value of a `let` variable as many times as you want, but you should only *declare* it once.

Comment: `greaterThanFive = true;` instead of `let greaterThanFive = true;`... you just want to change the value of the variable already declared, not re-declare it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `let` keyword defines a new variable within the *lexical scope*. The lexical scope in the case of this line:

```
function exerciseFour(value){
  let greaterThanFive = false;   // <----
  // ...
}
```

...is the function. The second `let` then *shadows* the first variable, meaning a nested lexical scope has a variable with the same name but completely detached from the original. Its scope is the if statement block:

```
function exerciseFour(value){
  let greaterThanFive = false; // <-- scoped to function
  if (value > 5) {
    let greaterThanFive = true;  // <-- define new variable, scoped to if statement
  }

  return greaterThanFive;
}
```

Therefore, once we *leave* the scope of that if statement block, `greaterThanFive` references the *function-scoped* variable, which is why it still has the value `false`.

Simply removing the second `let` will cause the statement to be an *assignment* statement rather than a *variable declaration*:

```
function exerciseFour(value){
  let greaterThanFive = false;
  if (value > 5) {
    greaterThanFive = true; // Assigns a new value to the variable
  }

  return greaterThanFive;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>You can't declaration variable second time</s>.

Deleting the second `let` will solve your problem.

```
function exerciseFour(value){
  let greaterThanFive = false;

  if (value > 5) {
     greaterThanFive = true; // <--- Remove `let` here.
  }

  return greaterThanFive;
}

function exerciseFive(name){
  let isSondra = false;

  if (name === 'Sondra') {
     isSondra = true;
  }

  return isSondra;
}

console.log(exerciseFour(3));
console.log(exerciseFour(7));
console.log(exerciseFive("Matt"));
console.log(exerciseFive("Sondra"));
```

Comment: "You can't declaration variable second time" - you can, `let` is block scoped. It will just shadow the outer one, and not perform what is intended at all. To elaborate on this: `let x = 0; const f = p => x = p; if (true) { let x = 5; f(x); x = 0; console.log(x); } console.log(x);`

Comment: sorry my bad i didn't know